# Does anyone one know how to translate this jQuery into normal js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

So i have an email sending function on my cordova app and it uses jQuery to do it. When debugging my app the ajax function works fine when testing in my browser, but when i build the app and test it on my phone it does not work. I had another problem like this that was only fixed once i used normal js instead of jQuery. Here is the function:

```
var message = localStorage.getItem("Message");
var key = "dJdJekCVAFIqvUJ13DEczZjgIh_4MyeIGEHz2GBYKFe"; // <<KEY
var message_name = "defender_send_message";    // <<MESSAGE NAME
var url = "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/" + message_name + "/with/key/" + key;
$.ajax({  // <<SEND
  url: url,
  data: {value1: message,
         value2: localStorage.getItem("AdminsEmail")},
  dataType: "jsonp",
  complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log("Message Sent");
  } 
});
```

Does anyone know how to translate it into normal js? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean "instead of jQuery"? AJAX is a general technique, not something specific to code.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah i think i dont use much jQuery and dont know the correct terminology. Ill edit my post now

Comment: You should probably try to figure out why jQuery isn't working in your app. Rewriting everything that uses it will probably be a big task.

Comment: @Barmar Its okay, i dont use jquery often in the app.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `XMLHttpRequest` object to make a `ajax` call using vanilla JS.

```
var message = localStorage.getItem("Message");
var key = "dJdJekCVAFIqvUJ13DEczZjgIh_4MyeIGEHz2GBYKFe";
var message_name = "defender_send_message";
var url = "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/" + message_name + "/with/key/" + key;
var data = {};

data.value1 = message;
data.value2 = localStorage.getItem("AdminsEmail");

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log("Message Sent");
    }
  }
}

xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
xmlhttp.responseType = 'jsonp';
xmlhttp.send(data);
```

Comment: Would the "url" value be the same as the original one? The reason i ask is that you didnt use the "key"  value

Comment: @sparpo Yes, the URL is the same.

Comment: You can't send an object with `xmlhttp.send`. You need to perform the URL-encoding that jQuery normally does for you.

Comment: @Barmar Do you know how to do this?

Comment: `data = 'value1=' + encodeURIComponent(message) + '&value2=' + encodeURIComponent(locaStorage.getItem("AdminsEmail"));`

Comment: Or may be send it as `FormData` object .  `xmlhttp.send(new FormData(data));`